# Sending external email as distribution group in ASP .Net

Tags: email, exchange-server, smtpclient

first off, not sure if this question should have been on serverfault vs. stackoverflow, sorry if it is in the wrong spot.

I am having a problem sending email to outside emails from my ASP .Net application where the "from" address is a distribution group.  I will try to lay everything out:

**Email Server**: Exchange 2010

I have a domain user "websmtp" that was created in order to perform authenticated sending.

I am trying to send the mail from webmaster@company.com.  This is a distribution (may actually be a security group?).  I want to do this so the replys to my emails will go to the group.  Nobody will be monitoring the websmtp user's mailbox.

**Here is the web.config smtp section**

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="webmaster@company.com">
            <network host="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" userName="websmtp" password="thepassword" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

**Sample email code:**

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
mm.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");
mm.Subject = "this is a test";
mm.Body = "this is a test";
mm.IsBodyHtml = false;

SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient();
s.Send(mm);
```

This code fails with a message from Exchange "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender".  The "websmtp" user was granted SendOnBehalfOf permissions to the "webmaster" group using the Set-DistributionGroup command.

I **CAN** send on behalf of the webmaster user when logged in as the websmtp user either through Windows or through my companies OWA webmail to both internal and external users.

At this point I am really just looking for suggestions for what to ask our Exchange admin to try or if there is anything else I can try in my web.config.  I can't really code around this because a lot of the emails that I am generating come directly from the ASP .Net membership wizards.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like an authentication issue to me. it looks like you are setting the username and password, but maybe they are either incorrect or the credentials are not be passed correctly.

Comment: I took the part of my question out about adding my companies domain before the username.  Thanks to your suggestion I used Wireshark to sniff the connection and sure enough, there was an authentication failure when using that.  It is successful without it however, which still leaves me confused as to why I can send on behalf of the group through webmail but not code.  Thanks for taking the time to answer.